# if..while.. if .. loop strange issue

Tags: php, mysqli

Simple, yet i cannot figure out whats wrong. 
Scenario: I have a page called stationary. And item pen has been reviewed(clicked). Bottom sample code is a search feature, to list the related items.

Code:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 
/* Code to display item*/

$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1_category = 'red'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 2){
echo "No other red pen available.";
}else{
     while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($data['item_id'] == '$id'){
           echo "";
        }else{
           echo $data['item_name']."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

My error: ID from the table is displaying incorrect while debugging.
There seems to be a problem with inner if statement.

or is there!?

Fixed/Solved:

```
if($data['item_id'] == $id){
........
}else{}
```

Comment: `'$id'` does not interpolate variables. Use plain old `$id`. If you need to include text then use double quotes for variable interpolation: `"Hey there, $name!"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($data[item_id] == '$id'){
```

There's no definition of `item_id`.  If it's a variable, those usually begin with a `$`.  This is probably resulting in errors in your PHP logs (which you should really check).  Perhaps you meant for it to be a string?

```
if($data['item_id'] == '$id'){
```

Also, will that value ever equal the *literal string* `'$id'`?  Or did you mean to use the *variable* `$id`?

```
if($data['item_id'] == $id){
```

Comment: it is a variable $id, from GET. Thanks for the enlightenment, i figured it out, the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement

```
if($data['item_id'] == '$id')
```

should be replaced with

```
if($data['item_id'] == $id)
```

or as your intention

```
if($data['item_id'] == "$id")
```

If $id = 10, "$id" would be "10" but '$id' wouldn't be transformed.